# Можно ли разместить функцию в переменную php

Tags: php, html

Можно ли задавать функцию внутри переменной таким образом:

```
$Content = <<<'CODE'<div class="somestuff">Tralala</div>
LoginFunction(0)
CODE;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/104516/7815487

Comment: @MedvedevDev заметьте, здесь приведен nowdoc синтаксис а не heredoc

Comment: @teran, оу, да, упустил, тогда замечание отклоняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP замыкания выглядят так:

```
<?php

$LoginFunctiont1 = function() {
    return 'Tralala 1';
};

$LoginFunctiont2 = function() use ($LoginFunctiont1) {
    return 'Tralala 2 <br />'. $LoginFunctiont1();
};

echo $LoginFunctiont2('LoginFunctiont1');
/* Результат:
Tralala 2 
Tralala 1
*/
```

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо огромное. Скажите, пожалуйста, а если допустим надо вместить туда две функции, то как это сделать?

Comment: @lovo в одну переменную не выйдет. Но можно в теле функции вызвать другую пользовательскую ф-цию. Вы лучше опишите задание.

Comment: @lovo подправил свой ответ.

Comment: Там очень много кода, вкратце здесь не выйдет написать, хотя если интересно, то могу скинуть. Суть такова: есть шапка сайта, я ее загнал в PHP функцию, чтобы не копировать ее на каждой странице снова, для удобства, при этом шапка тоже имеет функцию логина пользователя. Функция работала нормально, но я решил что лучше не кидать много HTML кода в одну функцию и добавил переменных. Вот теперь мучаюсь :)

Comment: @lovo так может быть лучше использовать не замыкания, а обычные пользовательские функции? Их так же, как и замыкания из моего примера, можно вызывать в теле функции, и в отличии от замыканий не нужно дописывать оператор `use`.